# Detecting full screen mode in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to detect if some application is currently running in full screen mode. If yes, then I must stop my application. So, how can I detect that? 
p.s. Win32 C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
RECT appBounds;
RECT rc;
GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rc);
```

Then check if that windows isn't desktop or shell.
Simple if instruction.

```
if(hWnd =! GetDesktopWindow() && hWnd != GetShellWindow())
{
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &appBounds);
    // Now you just have to compare rc to appBounds
}
```

This is written without testing.

Answer (score 21):

*All other answers are rather hackish.*

Windows Vista, Windows 7 and up support [`SHQueryUserNotificationState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shqueryusernotificationstate):

```
QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE pquns;
SHQueryUserNotificationState(&pquns);
```

From this "notification state" it is possible to infer the fullscreen state. Basically, when there is an an app running in fullscreen mode, Windows reports a "busy" notification state.

- `QUNS_NOT_PRESENT` - not fullscreen (machine locked/screensaver/user switching)
- `QUNS_BUSY` – fullscreen (the F11 fullscreen, also all video games I tried use this)
- `QUNS_RUNNING_D3D_FULL_SCREEN` – fullscreen (Direct3D application is running in exclusive mode, i.e. fullscreen)
- `QUNS_PRESENTATION_MODE` – fullscreen (a special mode for showing presentations, which are fullscreen)
- `QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS` – not fullscreen
- `QUNS_QUIET_TIME` – not fullscreen
- `QUNS_APP` – probably fullscreen (not sure: *"Introduced in Windows 8. A Windows Store app is running."*)

Comment: Actually this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the most fast forward. for windowHandle check user can have autohide taskbar. This function gives the full state of fullscreen info.

Answer (score 7):

Hooch's and ens' answers actually don't work on a multiple monitor system. That's because

> The rectangle of the desktop window returned by GetWindowRect or GetClientRect is always equal to the rectangle of the primary monitor, for compatibility with existing applications.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/multiple-monitor-system-metrics
for reference.

The above means that if the window is fullscreen on a monitor that's not the primary monitor of the system, the coordinates (which are relative to the virtual screen) are completely different from the coordinates of the desktop window.

I fixed this with the following function:

```
bool isFullscreen(HWND windowHandle)
{
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo = { 0 };
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(windowHandle, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), &monitorInfo);

    RECT windowRect;
    GetWindowRect(windowHandle, &windowRect);

    return windowRect.left == monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left
        && windowRect.right == monitorInfo.rcMonitor.right
        && windowRect.top == monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top
        && windowRect.bottom == monitorInfo.rcMonitor.bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A full implementation of Hooch's answer:

```
bool isFullscreen(HWND window)
{
    RECT a, b;
    GetWindowRect(window, &a);
    GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &b);
    return (a.left   == b.left  &&
            a.top    == b.top   &&
            a.right  == b.right &&
            a.bottom == b.bottom);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's also a `Java` [`JNA`](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) implementation based on [ens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44898068/3764804)' answer:

```
public static boolean isFullScreen()
{
    WinDef.HWND foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    WinDef.RECT foregroundRectangle = new WinDef.RECT();
    WinDef.RECT desktopWindowRectangle = new WinDef.RECT();
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(foregroundWindow, foregroundRectangle);
    WinDef.HWND desktopWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetDesktopWindow();
    User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(desktopWindow, desktopWindowRectangle);
    return foregroundRectangle.toString().equals(desktopWindowRectangle.toString());
}
```

Note that the `toString()` comparison at the bottom is a small hack to avoid comparing 4 elements to each other.

Comment: WinDef.HWND foregroundWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();                     for jna 5.5