# Is there any event when an application enter into full screen mode and quit full screen mode in Windows？

Tags: windows, winapi, fullscreen

My app should know when does an application enter into full screen mode and quit full screen mode? I have found this question [Detecting full screen mode in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009080/detecting-full-screen-mode-in-windows). But the solutions need my app to detect the state in periods. I want to know is there any event to notify my app? Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when a window is maximized? If so, there are some pointers in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436795/setwineventhook-window-maximized-event).

Comment: No. Full screen mode is different with maximizing window. For example, you can press F11 to enter into the full screen mode in Edge. And in full screen mode, the address bar and tab bar will be hidden.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook

Comment: With `SetWinEventHook`, registering `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`. When the ObjectId is `OBJID_WINDOW`. The handle of the Window is passed to the delegate. You can then check whether the ClientArea fills the entire Screen (not WorkingArea).

Comment: It's not clear whether you want your program to detect itself going to full screen mode or you want to detect another process. In first case you simply handle `WM_SIZE` message.

Comment: I want to detect another process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an event called "fullscreenchange", this will trigger when you toggle between full screen mode (enter/exit full screen mode).

Comment: I have search web for the "fullscreenchange", but I couldn't find any documents about "fullscreenchange" for Windows. I only found a web API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenchange_event. Can you share some documents about how to use this api in Windows.